# Why can't I use $event to receive an array of strings?

Tags: angular, typescript

when i tried to pass info from  a child to a parent using event emmiter and  Output i get this error:

```
Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string[]'.
  Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'string[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.ngtsc(2345)
```

this is the child code

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-calculator-buttons',
  templateUrl: './buttons.component.html',
  styleUrl: './buttons.component.css'
})
export class ButtonsComponent {
  public firstRow:string[]=["7","8","9","+","="];
  public secondRow:string[]=["4","5","6","*","/"];
  public thirdRow:string[]=["1","2","3","-","AC"];
  public fourthRow:string[]=["0",".","(",")"];
  @Output()
  public onNewresult:EventEmitter<string[]>=new EventEmitter();
  public screenValues:string[]=[];
  apagar():void{ 
    console.log("Apagado");
    let pantalla=document.getElementById("pantalla") as HTMLInputElement;
    pantalla.value="";
 
}
 operaciones():void{
  let pantalla=document.getElementById("pantalla") as HTMLInputElement;
  this.screenValues.unshift(pantalla.value);//añado el valor de la operacion al princio del array 
  let operacion:number=eval(pantalla.value);//eval trasfoma una cadena en una operacion matematica
  pantalla.value=operacion.toString();
  this.screenValues[0]+="= "+pantalla.value;
  this.emitResult();
  //usar services para pasar datos desde buttons hasta screen

}

monitor(index:string):void{
 let pantalla=document.getElementById("pantalla") as HTMLInputElement;
 pantalla.value+=index;
}
 emitResult():void{
  this.onNewresult.emit({...this.screenValues})
} 
}
```

and this is the parent code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-page',
  templateUrl: './main-page.component.html',
  styleUrl: './main-page.component.css'
})
export class MainPageComponent {

 onNewResult(arreglo:string[]):void{
  console.log("Resultado recibido");
  console.log({arreglo});
 }

}
```

there is where i use the $event to get the event by child

```
<div class="container bg-secondary rounded  my-2 p-2" id="contenedor">
  <calculator-body (onNewResult)="onNewResult($event)"></calculator-body><
  <app-calculator-buttons></app-calculator-buttons>
</div>
```

I am using Angular and Typescript, what can i do to remove that error?

I try to pass an array of strings from a child component to a parent component to do this, I use @Output and EventEmmiter, the method manages to access the child component (the message appears in the console), but it never gets into the component, the error appears that $event is not assignable to the type array of strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the event Emitter to string, but you are emitting an object which is confusing. So I converted the code to emit an array, instead of an object.

```
emitResult(): void {
    this.onNewresult.emit([...this.screenValues]);
}
```

We can change the event `onNewResult` argument to `string[]` which will solve the issue!

```
onNewresult(data: string[]): void {
    console.log(data);
}
```

working example below.

child

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-calculator',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule],
  template: `
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value"/>
    <button (click)="operaciones()">operaciones</button>
  `,
})
export class CalculatorComponent {
  value = '';
  public firstRow: string[] = ['7', '8', '9', '+', '='];
  public secondRow: string[] = ['4', '5', '6', '*', '/'];
  public thirdRow: string[] = ['1', '2', '3', '-', 'AC'];
  public fourthRow: string[] = ['0', '.', '(', ')'];
  @Output()
  public onNewresult: EventEmitter<string[]> = new EventEmitter<string[]>();
  public screenValues: string[] = [];
  apagar(): void {
    console.log('Apagado');
    this.value = '';
  }
  operaciones(): void {
    let pantallaValue = this.value;
    this.screenValues.unshift(pantallaValue); //añado el valor de la operacion al princio del array
    let operacion: number = eval(pantallaValue); //eval trasfoma una cadena en una operacion matematica
    pantallaValue = operacion.toString();
    this.screenValues[0] += '= ' + pantallaValue;
    this.emitResult();
    //usar services para pasar datos desde buttons hasta screen
  }

  monitor(index: string): void {
    let pantalla = document.getElementById('pantalla') as HTMLInputElement;
    pantalla.value += index;
  }
  emitResult(): void {
    this.onNewresult.emit([...this.screenValues]);
  }
}
```

parent

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { CalculatorComponent } from './calculator/calculator.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule, CalculatorComponent],
  template: `
    <app-calculator (onNewresult)="onNewresult($event)"/>
  `,
})
export class App {
  onNewresult(data: string[]) {
    console.log(data);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-4hifdk?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fcalculator%2Fcalculator.component.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)